# queries in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How to query Employee to get all the address related to the employee,      `Employee.Add.all()`  does not work..

```
 class Employee():
    Add = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(Parent, blank=True, null=True)

class Address(models.Model):
   address_emp = models.CharField(max_length=512)
   description = models.TextField()

   def __unicode__(self):
   return self.name()
```

Comment: Did you really mean to write `Employee.Add.all()`? `Employee` is the class, not an instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Employee.objects.get(pk=1).Add.all()

You need to show **which** employee do you mean. `pk=1` is obviously an example (employee with primary key equal to 1).

BTW, there is a strong convention to use lowercase letters for field names. `Employee.objects.get(pk=1).addresses.all()` would look much better.

Answer (score 2):

`Employee.Add.all()` does not work because you are trying to access a related field from the Model and this kind of queries require an instance of the model, like Ludwik's example. To access a model and its related foreign key field in the same query you have to do something like this:

```
Employee.objects.select_related('Add').all()
```

That would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`employee = Employee.objects.prefetch_related('Add')
[emp.Add.all() for emp in employee]`

prefetch_related supports many relationships and caches the query set and reduces the database hits hence increases the performance..